# Which ones of $n$ random variables have the largest mean (non-parametric way)?

Tags: matlab, nonparametric, ranking, extreme-value

Let us have $n$ random, mutually independent variables $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$. Let us have some samples of them such as $x_{i,j}$ where $i=1,\dots,n$. I want to know the maximal variable(s) based on those data. These data are results from real-world experiments with $n$ different settings and the only thing I need is to determine the winning settings.

More specifically, I want to find such a subset of indices $A\equiv\{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_m\}\subseteq B\equiv \{1,\dots,n\}$ such that

- $\forall i,i'\in A:\mathcal{E}[X_i]\simeq\mathcal{E}[X_{i'}]$
- and $\forall i,\in A,i'\in B\backslash A:\mathcal{E}[X_i]\gtrsim\mathcal{E}[X_{i'}]$

Where $\mathcal{E}[\cdot]$ stands for the expected value and $\simeq,\gtrsim$ shall be read as equal/less than with respect to data available.

My attempt:

1. To set $A\gets B$
2. To compare each $X_i$ and $X_{i'}$ using a test. Whenever I reject the hypothesis $\mathcal{E}[X_i]= \mathcal{E}[X_{i'}]$ in favor of $\mathcal{E}[X_i]< \mathcal{E}[X_{i'}]$, set $A\gets A \backslash \{i\}$, i.e. remove $i$ from $A$.

A simple Matlab example follows:

```
Ndata = 50;
X(:,1) = randn(Ndata,1);
X(:,2) = randn(Ndata,1)+0.1;
X(:,3) = randn(Ndata,1)+0.5;
X(:,4) = 3*randn(Ndata,1)+0.5;
n = 4;
A = 1:n;
for i=1:n
    for iPrime=1:n
        if ttest2(X(:,i),X(:,iPrime),'Alpha',0.05,'Tail','left')>0
            A=setdiff(A,i);
        end
    end
end
```

In that case the result tends to be `A = [3 4]`.

Would you recommended something more tailored or established for this task? Possibly non-parametric and in Matlab.

I noticed that there is a related question ([Ranking randomly distributed variables based on decreasingness](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34641/ranking-randomly-distributed-variables-based-on-decreasingness)) but it speaks about something else. It has perhaps something to do with Bonferoni corrections, but I am not sure about that point.

Comment: Please tell us what a "maximal variable" is.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I do need to check, though, that you meant what you wrote. You seem to be looking for a subset of variables with maximal expectations among them all. However, by employing a K-S test and referring to "non-dominated variables" you are checking something totally different: you are comparing entire distributions and perhaps have in mind stochastic dominance.  Which sense of "maximal" is the one you *really* mean?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, exactly?

Comment: @ArthurB. I have $n$ different approaches how to run a physical experiment and I want to decide which ones are the top, based on the results of the experiments. Perhaps my formulations are not clear enough, but this is the core of what I need.

Comment: The problem is what is "the top" can depend on how you measure it. You have to be more precise about what you mean by that.

Comment: To give a concrete example, imagine that you have two approaches. You think approach $A$ has value either $1, 2$, or $10^9$ (with probability $1/3$ each) each and approach $B$ has value $3$ for sure. $B>A$ is more likely than $A>B$, but you might still want to pick $A$ over $B$, it depends on your utility function.

Comment: @ArthurB. Thanks, your comment is interesting. However, I decided after all comments above to specify my utility function to be a mean. In that case your $A$ would be the option for sure. The challenge is elsewhere: how to run multiple comparison based on data and how to construct the set $A$ (which is something completely different from your random variable $A$).

Comment: It's not going to be a set. One variable will typically have the highest sample mean, and that's it. When you think of a set of maximal elements, you're thinking of the true, underlying value (which might be discrete). But by taking the expectation you're looking at a statistical measurement. The "max" you're taking includes your uncertainty.

Comment: To put it another way, you have a choice to be uncertain about which one is the max, or to take the max of uncertain values. You've chosen the latter.

Comment: It is a good point. There will be just one variable with max expected value. However, with respect to my data and with respect to the non-paramteric settings I will never be sure fully. The set I am looking shall contain those variables that I admit to be maximal with respect to the available data.

Answer (score 2):

If you're prepared to assume that any distributional differences result from one variable being stochastically larger than the other (e.g. for continuous r.v.s, $P(X>Y)>\frac12$), a Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney statistic is a linear function of a natural estimator of $P(X>Y)$ (whether you're interested in a test or not, the estimator itself can be informative).

With more than two groups, the closest equivalent is the Kruskal-Wallis test, which is a form of rank-based one-way analysis of variance.

If you're purely interested in differences in mean, you can just look at differences in mean -- this can be turned into a nonparametric test by using difference in sample means as a test statistic in a permutation test, (or weighted sums of squared differences of group means* from the overall mean with more than two groups).

One advantage of looking at means is that mean differences are necessarily transitive, while $P(X>Y)>\frac12$ effects are not. However, once we look at statistical significance, you can get what seem to be unintuitive outcomes even with means.

* in effect the numerator of the usual F-statistic (or indeed the F-statistic itself could be used in a permutation test)

Comment: Thank you for you answer, however the core is rather about dealing with $n$ samples/variables instead of 2 which is quite common in the literature.